# Should this table be a dimension table or a fact table in a data warehouse

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

[image: HR TABLE with Shift Details]

The above Table has call center employee shift/target details

- OperatorID,
- User_Name as Operator Name,
- Team_Id,
- Team Name the Operator belongs to,
- FTE = number of days employee works in a week.(example: FTE = 0.8 = 6.4 Hours)

Each row may or may not change every week.

I feel this is a slowly changing dimension but I also have a strange feeling that this could be a fact table.

Comment: If this were a dimension, it wouldnt have both the user's  and team's name; as there would be a different dimension for the details of the user/team. This feels like it's a fact table, with data it shouldn't have (and should be in the related dimensions).

Comment: Agree with Larnu. This is an accumulating fact with dimensions of Operator and Team.

Comment: Why should team and operator be separate dimensions? Wouldn't operators be present as a column in team dimension? The data in the picture may change every single day. sometimes same data gets uploaded everyday indicating nothing has changed.